# primefaces and JSF 2.3 javascript error Cannot read property 'error' of null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.3

I am using primefaces with JSF2.3

here is the way my dependencies are

```
    dependencies {

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.0'
    compile group: 'javax.faces', name: 'javax.faces-api', version: '2.3'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.faces', version: '2.3.3'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet:2.4.5.Final'
    compile group: 'org.primefaces', name: 'primefaces', version: '6.2'
}
```

my jsf file is very basic

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<f:view>
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
    <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{testView.chosen}"
                         style="width:200px">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select listing template"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{testView.list}"/>
            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@all"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</html>
```

and my viewScoped bean also

```
    @Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestView implements Serializable {
String chosen;
List<String> list;

@PostConstruct
public void setup(){
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("alpha");
    list.add("gamma");
    list.add("bravo");
}
```

getter and setter are ommited for simplicity.

the thing is that I used to work with (jsf 2.2, primefaces 6.1) and everything is working fine.

after the upgrade (jsf 2.3, primefaces6.2), I have a problem whenever the event change (when i change selection is triggered)

the  error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at i (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:2)
    at A (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:4)
```

Is there any conflict javascript between jsf2.3 and primefaces ?

Comment: So you actually used  **PrimeFaces 6.2** with JSF 2.2 and did not get this error? Sure you did not upgrade PrimeFaces? And by accident have 2 PrimeFaces versions in your **deployed** project?

Comment: And `update="@all"` should rarely be used... Does it work if you do not use that? Assuming your example is an [mcve] it should work if you remove that

Answer (score 7):

AFAICS this is a bug in Mojarra, i would create a issue there.
Seems like the component resources are available (see PrimeFaces HeadRenderer) in the postback but somehow they are not rendered in the response inside the head tag.

NOTE: this will only happen with update=@all as otherwise the head-tag won't be replaced. Actually update=@all shoudln't be used, only if really really really necessary.

Comment: *Actually update=@all shoudln't be used, only if really really really necessary* hear, hear...

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with mojarra, because it should send all the files when you want to render "all".

Meanwhile, there is an alternative solution mentioned here:
https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4354

You can execute the following script after primeface has loaded, so it can change the way PF renders the HEAD:

https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/files/2626517/primefaces_replacehead_hack.js.txt

With it, PF wont replace the head and the code will probably continue to work.

It worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately both links are broken now :(
However, there is https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4354 and https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4553 with at least some information.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your factual question (which is imo wrongly formulated),

> Is there any conflict javascript between jsf2.3 and primefaces ?

The answer is:

No there is not. Since the PrimeFaces showcase is 
"Running PrimeFaces-6.2 on Mojarra-2.3.2" according to the bottom of the actual operational showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/

But your edit to me suggests (like I posted in my comments) you have multiple PF versions in your actual running project.

Answer (score 0):

I can create this issue on PrimeFaces 6.2 and 6.3-SNAPSHOT ShowCase with simplified markup. The primefaces core javascript files are missing in the delivered content. After update body the global primefaces variable is undefined / null. Using @form instead of @all is still working.

(minified) index.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="BUTTON_TEXT" update="@all"
            process="@none" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

(minified) template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="body"></ui:insert>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Stacktrace:

```
VM47:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cw' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:12
    at p (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:2)
    at Ja (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at r.fn.init.append (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at T (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at r.fn.init.html (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at Object.updateBody (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at Object.updateElement (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
    at Object.doUpdate (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2:3)
```

Open: https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4354

Comment: Is this an answer or a new question?